# how I can set binary data in a char[]

Tags: c++, c

I have const binary data that I need insert to buffer
for example

```
 char buf[] = "1232\0x1";
```

but how can do it when binary data is at first like below

```
 char buf[] = "\0x11232";
```

compiler see it like a big hex number
but my perpose is

```
 char buf[] = {0x1,'1','2','3','2'};
```

Comment: `\0x1` isn't hex for 1 but a NULL byte followed by the characters 'x' and '1'

Comment: You can't use either of your first two snippets.  Just do it long hand like your third snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compile-time string concatenation:

```
char buf[] = "\x01" "1232";
```

<strike>However, with a 2-digit number after `\x` it also works without:</strike>

```
char buf[] = "\x011232";
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  The escape sequence will consume more than two characters in the second example.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784969/163956

Answer (score 3):

You can create a single string literal by composing it of adjacent strings - the compiler will concatenate them:

```
char buf[] = "\x1" "1232";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char buf[] = {0x1,'1','2','3','2', 0};  // note the terminating null, which may or may not be important to you
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it in two byte or four byte format:

```
\xhh = ASCII character in hexadecimal notation

\xhhhh = Unicode character in hexadecimal notation if this escape sequence is used in a wide-character constant or a Unicode string literal.
```

so in your case you have to write `"\x0112345"`