# strlen - the length of the string is sometimes increased by 1

Tags: c, string, strlen

I'm doing some C puzzle questions. In most cases, I am able to find the right answer, but with that one I am having problems. I know the right answer by using the compiler, but I don't know the reason.

Have a look at the code:

```
char c[] = "abc\012\0x34";
```

What would `strlen(c)` return, using a Standard C compiler?

My compiler returns 4 when what I expected was 3.

What I thought is `strlen()` would search for the first occurrence of the `NULL` character but somehow the result is one more than I expected.

Any idea why?

Comment: `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a *null pointer constant*. Using that it to refer to the null character `'\0'` is potentially confusing.

Comment: Continuing on Keith's comment, the term for `'\0'` is `NUL` (with only one L).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let's write

```
char c[] = "abc\012\0x34";
```

with single characters:

```
char c[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\012', '\0', 'x', '3', '4', '\0' };
```

The first `\0` you see is the start of an octal escape sequence `\012` that extends over the following octal digits.

Octal escape sequences are specified in section 6.4.4.4 of the standard (N1570 draft):

> *octal-escape-sequence:*
>      `\` *octal-digit*
>      `\` *octal-digit octal-digit*
>      `\` *octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit*

they consist of a backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits. In paragraph 7 of that section, the extent of octal and hexadecimal escape sequences is given:

> 7 Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can
>   constitute the escape sequence.

Note that while the length of an octal escape sequence is limited to at most three octal digits (thus `"\123456"` consists of five characters, `{ '\123', '4', '5', '6', '\0' }`), hexadecimal escape sequences have unlimited length

> *hexadecimal-escape-sequence:*
>       `\x` *hexadecimal-digit*
>       *hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit*

and thus `"\x123456789abcdef"` consists of only two characters (`{ '\x123456789abcdef', '\0' }`).

Comment: I'm sure you can find some comfort in your remaining seventy thousand rep.

Comment: @effeffe, This has the potential to end up as a gold votes badge. Is that good enough?

Comment: @chris It sure looks like it can get me silver, but gold would be embarrassing.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I haven't seen anything like this on SO. It fits a pretty good niche.

Comment: If `\012` is octal then why `\0x34` is not hexadecimal **?** Didn't get.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Because hexadecimal escape sequences start with `\x`, not `\0x`, a hexadecimal escape sequence would be `'\x34'`. In `"...\0x34..."`, the `'\0'` is an octal escape sequence, followed by the three ordinary characters `'x'`, `'3'` and `'4'`. I don't know why hexadecimal escape sequences start `\x` and not `\0x`, I suppose it's easier to parse if the type of escape sequence is determined immediately after the backslash.

Comment: One might also be interested in [when did C++ compilers start considering more than two hex digits in string literal character escapes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784969/459391). It seems to be about `g++`, but `gcc` produces the same warning as well.