# Explain Backslash in C

Tags: c, escaping, backslash, slash

Can anyone please explain the below code and please also explain the role of backslash( `\` ) in such situations. And what `\'` , `\"` , `\ooo` , `\ \` , `\?` means?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a = '\010';
    char y = '010';
    printf("%d,%d",a,y);

    return 0;
}
```

output: 8,48

Comment: Read [Printing char by integer qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183764/printing-char-by-integer-qualifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `'\010'` is a *octal escape sequence* `10` in octal is `8` in decimal and it will be promoted to an `int` when calling `printf` so that explains that value.

This `'010'` is a *multi-character constant* and it's value is implementation defined, if we look at the C99 draft standard section `6.4.4.4` *Character constants* paragraph *10* says(*emphasis mine*):

> [...]The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined.[...]

and if you were using `gcc` you would have seen at least this warning:

> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

and probably this warning as well on overflow:

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

the value that `y` obtains is a little more interesting since *character constant* has an integer value it can not just be taking the first character, the *multi-character constant* has to take an *integer* value and then be converted to *char*. `clang` helpfully provides a more detailed warning:

> warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 3158320 to 48 [-Wconstant-conversion]

and current versions of `gcc` produces the same value, as we can see from this simple piece of code:

```
printf("%d\n",'010');
```

so where does `3158320` comes from? For `gcc` at least, if we look at the documentation for [Implementation-defined behavior](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html) it says:

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not (a slight change from versions 3.1 and earlier of GCC). If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.

if we perform the operation(*assuming 8-bit char*) document above we see:

```
 48*2^16 + 49*2^8 + 48  = 3158320
 ^         ^
 |         decimal value of ASCII '1'
 decimal value of ASCII '0'
```

`gcc` will convert the `int` to `char` using modulus `2^8` regardless of whether `char` is *signed* or *unsigned* which effectively leaves us with the last `8` bits or `48`.

Comment: Suspect the true originator of this question used `010` to avoid an endian issue.  I suspect for char y = `123`, on a little endian machine, will get the value of `3` (or 51 ASCII) and `1` (or 49 ASCII) on a big endian machine.  In any case, as you say, multi-byte can have portability issues especially with variant endian and `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, `\010` is interpreted as an octal which results in `8`.

In the second case, the ascii value of `0` (the first character in `010`) is returned, which is `48`.

If you had compiler warnings on, chances are that you'd have figured the second one

```
char y = '010';
```

by yourself.  (`gcc` would have emitted `-Wmultichar` and `-Woverflow` in this case.)

---

Quoting [C1X draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section [6.4.4.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=85):

> An integer character constant has type **`int`**. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing a single character that maps to a
>   single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The
>   value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., **`'ab'`**), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, **is
>   implementation-defined**. If an integer character constant contains a
>   single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results
>   when an object with type **`char`** whose value is that of the single
>   character or escape sequence is converted to type **`int`**.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't suggest that `gcc` wouldn't say anything without explicitly enabling warnings.  I just said that the compiler in question might emit more information had debug flags been enabled.

Answer (score 5):

It is an *escape sequence* to remove meaning of some reserved character such as `'` or to specify some special character such as new-line `'\n'` or in this case a character with specific ASCII value:

```
char a = '\010';
```

defines a character with octal ASCII value 10<sub>8</sub>, i.e. decimal value 8<sub>10</sub>.

```
char y = '010';
```

defines a *multi-byte* character, which should be assigned to wide char, not `char`. Although the behavior of this assignment is not defined, in this case it will most likely cause the last character being stored, in `y`

Comment: How a multi-byte character can be store in a single byte container (`char`) ?

Comment: @Michael: It can not.

Comment: Actually it is a *multi-character constant*, I added the quote from *C99* in my answer.

Comment: @chux For `gcc` and as far as I can tell `clang` you are correct, I added more details wrt to this.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps:

```
\a  Beep
\b  Backspace
\f  Formfeed
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Horizontal tab
\v  Vertical tab
\\  Backslash
\'  Single quotation mark
\"  Double quotation mark
\0  ASCII 0x00 (nul terminator)
\ooo    Octal representation
\xdd    Hexadecimal representation
\xnn    Hexadecimal character code nn
\onn    Octal character code nn
\nn     Octal character code nn
```

Escape sequences are character combinations that comprise a backslash (\) followed by some character. When you're programming in almost all languages, sometimes you need to refer to a key press that doesn't result in a specific character.

For e.g. suppose you develop a language that assumes a variable to be enclosed with Box brackets `[var]` - then if you are inputting a value other than a variable then you will have to escape it like `\[10\]`. Otherwise your compiler will think that `10` is a variable name.

Comment: Your list is good, but could use ``\?` Question Mark` (C11dr 6.4.4.4).  Further, octal sequences are `'\'` followed by 1, 2 or 3 octal digits.  Hexadecimal sequences are `\x` followed by 1 or more hex digits (no limit). `\0` is the null character regardless if character coding is ASCII or not.

Answer (score 3):

It is an escape sequence - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C