# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ or '}' token

Tags: c

Please find below my function in C. I operate there using a stack which is part of another file, but that is working correctly.

```
void doOperation ( tStack* s, char c, char* postExpr, unsigned* postLen ) {
if ( ( c == ( '*' || '\' ) ) && ( s->arr[s->top] == ( '+' || '-' ) ) ) 
    stackPush( s, c); 
else if ( c == ( '+' || '-' ) && s->arr[s->top] == ( '*' || '/' ) ) {
    stackTop( s, postExpr[postLen] );
    *(postLen)++;
    stackPop( s );  
    stackPush( s, c);
}
else if ( c == '(' ) 
    stackPush( s, c);
else if ( c == ')' ) 
    untilLeftPar( s, postExpr, postLen);
else {
    stackTop( s, postExpr[postLen] );
    *(postLen)++;
    stackPop( s );  
    stackPush( s, c);
}
```

}

I get these errors and I have no idea what is wrong:

```
c204.c:70:23: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
c204.c:70:58: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
c204.c:70:65: warning: missing terminating ' character [enabled by default]
c204.c:70:2: error: missing terminating ' character
c204.c:71:3: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
c204.c:71:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
c204.c:88:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
c204.c:88:1: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
c204.c:88:1: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
../c202/c202.c: In function ‘stackTop’:
../c202/c202.c:100:18: warning: the comparison will always 
evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘stackEmpty’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
../c202/c202.c: In function ‘stackPop’:
../c202/c202.c:120:18: warning: the comparison will always 
evaluate as ‘true’ for the  address of ‘stackEmpty’ will never be NULL     [-Waddress]
../c202/c202.c: In function ‘stackPush’:
../c202/c202.c:133:17: warning: the comparison will always 
evaluate as ‘false’ for the address of ‘stackFull’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
make: *** [c204-test] Error 1
```

What might be the cause of these errors?

Comment: I don't know what you're using to edit your code, but in this case the syntax highlighting is a pretty decent indication of where things go wrong. And don't skip items in your compiler errors. You're focusing on the expected token error, where the first actual error (and warnings before it) are actually a better indicator of the problem.

Comment: Even the syntax-highlighting on StackOverflow catches it ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read about escape sequences, this `'\'` is the problem in the line:

```
 if ( ( c == ( '*' || '\' ) ) && ( s->arr[s->top] == ( '+' || '-' ) ) ) 
stackPush( s, c);
```

Replace it with `'\\'`:

```
if ( ( c == '*' || c == '\\' )  && ( ( s->arr[s->top] ==  '+' || s->arr[s->top] == '-' ) ) ) 
stackPush( s, c);
```

`\\` is for Backslash. For more [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493974/explain-backslash-in-c/19494048#19494048). Also the condition should not be written as `( c == ( '*' || '\\' ) )` - it should be `c == '*' || c == '\\'`

The `else if` portion is also slightly messed up, it should be something like:

```
else if ( ( c == '+' || c == '-' ) && ( s->arr[s->top] == '*' || s->arr[s->top] == '/' ) )
```

Also not sure if here `s->arr[s->top] == '/'` the `'/'` was a typo or not but if in case you needed backslash instead of `'/'` you will again have to use this `'\\'`.

Comment: actually `( c == ( '*' || '\\' ) )` should be `( c ==  '*' || c == '\\' )`

Comment: Correct `s->arr[s->top] == ( '+' || '-' )` also

Comment: Even the braces were an issue here. ;)

Comment: Not to mention the `else if` part as well.

Comment: No I think no braces and parenthesis mistake, the code in question is not correctly codified, Btw you introduced parenthesis mistake in you last `if`  statement, additionally in second if you have redundant parenthesis

Comment: The braces here `( '*' || '\' )` have no meaning actually.

Comment: Ok you mean parenthesis! Yes, actually `( c == ( '*' || '\\' ) )` is same as `c == 1`

Comment: thx guys for support i am beginner in C as you can see i will try it if will switch to ubuntu and i code in ubuntu as well

Comment: ok guy the mistake was that instead '\' should be '/' it was my missclick on keyboard or something now the error token is gone thx guys