# strlen sometimes equal to sizeof for null-terminated strings

Tags: c, string, null, sizeof, strlen

I know that `strlen` counts the number of characters up until (and excluding) the null character `'\0'` (or `0`) and that `sizeof` gives the amount of space needed to store the string including the null character, but am confused with the output of my code.

#### Question:

I expect the result of `strlen` to be consistently 1 less than the result of `sizeof` because my strings are null-terminated, but it only seems to be the case for the string of length 4 and 8, excluding '\0' (i.e. the 3rd and 5th results below).  I suspect it is the same reason that rubbish is being printed at the end of the string for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd results.  Could someone explain this behavior?

I read this related question, but I don't think that's what's happening here: [strlen - the length of the string is sometimes increased by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14264458/4716955).

#### What the code does:

In `main`, it creates an array of integers 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8.  And then for each of those lengths, it calls on the function `make_and_print_msgs` to:

- create a string of that length + 1 (for the null character), e.g. for a length of 4, the string "aaaa\0" is created
- print the message letter-by-letter using `%c` in `printf`
- print it as a string using `%s` in `printf`
- finds the `strlen` of the string
- finds the `sizeof` the string

#### Output:

```
i    data_length[i]
--------------------
0       0
msg intended to be:    
msg printed as string: �
strlen(msg): 1
sizeof(msg): 1

1       2
msg intended to be:    aa
msg printed as string: aaS
strlen(msg): 3
sizeof(msg): 3

2       4
msg intended to be:    aaaa
msg printed as string: aaaa
strlen(msg): 4
sizeof(msg): 5

3       6
msg intended to be:    aaaaaa
msg printed as string: aaaaaai
strlen(msg): 7
sizeof(msg): 7

4       8
msg intended to be:    aaaaaaaa
msg printed as string: aaaaaaaa
strlen(msg): 8
sizeof(msg): 9
```

#### Code:

(Sorry code is a bit long, that's why I explained it above.  Some comments in the code are references to Python NumPy functions.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>   /* needed for ceil */
#include <string.h> /* needed for strlen */

void make_linspace(int a[], double start, double stop, int num) {
    /* Fills array a[] (in place) with linearly spaced values just like np.linspace in NumPy (Python) */
    double spacing = (stop-start)/(num-1);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++){
        a[i] = start + i*spacing;
    }
}

void make_and_print_msgs(int n_proc, int msglength)
{
    /* Create a string called msg of length msglength + 1 (for the null character '\0') */
    char msg[msglength+1];
    int i;
    printf("msg intended to be:    ");
    for (i=0; i<msglength; i++) {
        msg[i] = 'a';
        printf("%c", msg[i]);
    }
    msg[i+1] = '\0';

    /* Print message to screen as a string and fine strlen(msg) and sizeof(msg) */
    printf("\n");
    printf("msg printed as string: %s\n", msg);
    printf("strlen(msg): %d\n", strlen(msg));
    printf("sizeof(msg): %d\n\n", sizeof(msg));

}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n_proc = 2;

    /* Create an array containing the lengths of strings to be printed (In this case, data_length should be {0, 2, 4, 6, 8} */
    int start = 0;
    int stop_range = 10;    /* the stop value if we are using range() */
    int step = 2;             /* spacing between the integers in the output of range() */
    int stop = stop_range - step;    /* the stop value if we are using linspace() */
    int npoints = (int) ceil( ((double)stop_range - (double)start) / (double)step );  /*  number of elements in the list produced by range(start, stop_range, step)  */

    int data_length[npoints];   /* 1D array of string lengths (# of non-null chars in each str) */
    make_linspace(data_length, start, stop, npoints);
    int i;


    /* For each length, call on make_and_print_msgs to make a string of that length (plus '\0') and then print to stdout */
    printf("   i    data_length[i]\n--------------------\n");
    for (i=0; i<npoints; i++) {
        printf("%4d %7d\n", i, data_length[i]);
        make_and_print_msgs(n_proc, data_length[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `msg[i+1] = '\0';` should be `msg[i] = '\0';`, as `msglength` is a last valid index of `msg` and `i` equals to it after a loop.

Comment: Oh my gosh! That was such a stupid mistake.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Don't print values of type `size_t` with `%d`. Use `%zu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this : `msg[i+1] = '\0';` to `msg[i] = '\0';`

You do not need to increment `i` as it is already incremented by the previous `for loop`.

Working ideone link: http://ideone.com/GJO1q1

Comment: Ah yes! I just realised what a stupid mistake I made.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `sizeof(msg)` always equals to `msglength+1` because you declared as `char msg[msglength+1];`.

`strlen(msg)` always counts till the first `'\0'` encountered. Thus in your code it is sometimes `msglength+1` and sometimes `msglength` depending on the initial content of uninitialized `msg`.

Comment: sizeof(msg) is msglength+1, not msglength.

Comment: @user3125367 Ouch, typo.