# Why does the size of this std::string change, when characters are changed?

Tags: c++, string, escaping

I have an issue in which the size of the string is effected with the presence of a `'\0'` character. I searched all over in SO and could not get the answer still.

Here is the snippet.

```
int main()
{
  std::string a = "123123\0shai\0";
  std::cout << a.length();
}
```

http://ideone.com/W6Bhfl

The output in this case is

```
6
```

Where as the same program with a different string having numerals instead of characters

```
int main()
{
  std::string a = "123123\0123\0";
  std::cout << a.length();
}
```

http://ideone.com/mtfS50

gives an output of

```
8
```

What exactly is happening under the hood? How does presence of a `'\0'` character change the behavior?

Comment: Do not put null characters (\0) in strings unless you have a very good idea what you are doing and why!

Comment: And if you do really need non-null-terminated strings, you'll want to use `std::literals::string_literals::operator""s` (C++14) or `std::string(char*, size_t)` (remember to include the final null if you want one).

Comment: Note that your second string replaces "shai" (four characters) with "123" (three characters), so there would be a difference even without the octal sequence mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: [You should have also searched in the C tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264458/strlen-the-length-of-the-string-is-sometimes-increased-by-1).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The sequence `\012` when used in a string (or character) literal is an *octal* escape sequence. It's the octal number `12` which corresponds to the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) linefeed (`'\n'`) character.

That means your second string is actually equal to `"123123\n3\0"` (plus the actual string literal terminator).

It would have been very clear if you tried to print the contents of the string.

Octal sequences are one to three digits long, and the compiler will use as many digits as possible.

Comment: Bingo! This was eating up my mind, thanks for answer.

Comment: Why isn't the first string length 12 and the second one 9?

Comment: ...and why is the second string length *larger* than the first?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because the `std::string` ctor taking a `const char*` treats it as a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @Angew Ah, sorry, you're right--so why not 13 and 10?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because it is "fooled" by the first `\0` in the buffer.

Comment: @KyleStrand It sounds like you need some exposure to C strings. They do not behave the same as strings in higher level languages like Java, C#, Python, etc. The "null character" (`\0`) has a special meaning in C strings; namely, it marks the end of the string.

Comment: @Angew Okay, you're right--I didn't think about the fact that `std::string(const char*)` must rely on null-termination of the argument to initialize the underlying data, since there's no other way for it to know the length of the string.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not sure what about my comments indicates that I don't understand how C strings work. My confusion was about the behavior of the `std::string` constructor invoked. Note that even in C++98, `std::string` *could* have had a constructor taking a `const char[]` *reference*, which would have allowed it to accept embedded `null` characters from string-literals: `std::string(const char (&ch)[N])`. This could have behaved identically to the `std::string(const char*, size_type count)` constructor.

Comment: .... I simply didn't realize that in fact this is not a constructor provided by `std::string`.

Answer (score 12):

If you check the coloring at [ideone](http://ideone.com/mtfS50) you will see that  `\012` has a different color. That is because this is a single character written in octal.

Comment: What *stops* the octal sequence inside a string?

Comment: @Raw  - Either the length of the sequence or a character that cannot be an octal digit. Like the s in `\0shai`.

Comment: is it possible to create literal with digits (0-7) following \0? only something like `"/0" + "12"` (or perhaps even that won't work?)

Comment: @slawekwin - You might have to separate the strings if you do *not* want to form a max length octal sequence, like `"12345" "\01" "678"`to have a character with ASCII 1 in the middle. The compiler will combine adjacent string literals. You can also get a std::string *including* the nul characters, if you use the string constructor with a length parameter, like `std::string a("123123\0shai\0", 12);`. That will include all 12 characters in the string.

Comment: @BoPersson : Clears a lot of air, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @slawekwin An octal character can have at most 3 digits, so `"\0007"` is two characters: `'\0'` and `'7'`.