# Printing a % sign in C using 'printf'

Tags: c

I am trying to print a `%` sign using *[printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)*.

I have tried with no luck:

```
printf("\%");
```

I'm sure it's really simple, but I've just started C.

Comment: It's `%%`. [Read the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: Related: [Why is percentage character not escaped with backslash in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811531/why-is-percentage-character-not-escaped-with-backslash-in-c) (though not necessarily duplicate)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `printf("%%");` The backslash is the escape character for C strings; the compiler interprets it. The percent sign is `printf`s escape character; the `printf` routine interprets it.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways:

```
printf("%%\n");
printf("%c\n", '%');
```

Comment: The second isn't really necessary. It's probably slow than first one.

Comment: @TheMask There's many ways to do the same thing...  just trying to demonstrate that to mitchellt

Answer (score 3):

Try by using the following escape sequence:

`%%`

Check out all [**escapes**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) usable in `*rintf()` functions family