# C - Print Character '%'

Tags: c

I was wondering if I could print % in c but when I use `printf("%")`
It just shows this syntax in output.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
   {
       printf("%");
   }
```

but the result is like this:

> main.c:13:13: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]

Does anybody know how I can literally print % as a character in c.

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274423/printing-a-sign-in-c-using-printf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a % sign in C using 'printf'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274423/printing-a-sign-in-c-using-printf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a `%` character you need to follow this structure:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%%");
    return 0;
}
```

you have to use the character twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
printf("%%");
```

or because `%` is a char, so you can use `%c`:

```
printf("%c", '%');
```

Overall, you have two ways.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("%%\n");
   printf("%c\n", '%');
}
```

will prints:

```
%
%
```

Answer (score 0):

The good old method would be to use the %c format specifier in printf() function

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
   {
       printf("%c",'%');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%%");
    return 0;
}
```