# error: hex escape sequence out of range

Tags: objective-c

Trying to compare to a string:
`BOOL r = [res isEqualToString:[@"\x124Vx\xc3\xaa"]];`

However I got

> error: hex escape sequence out of range

I tried also something like:

```
NSString *s = [@"\x12" stringByAppendingString: @"4Vx\xc3\xaa"];
BOOL r = [res isEqualToString:s];
```

Now it could work and return `YES`

How can I specify such string and avoiding splitting them up first? It's kind of annoying...

*UPDATE*:
I use @rmaddy's code, and it works now, however, If I put it in array like:

```
NSArray *answers = @[
                     @"",
                     @"#",
                     @"\x12""4Vx\xc3\xaa",
                     ]
```

It will generate a warning for the last string literal:

> Concatenated NSString literal for an NSArray expression - possibly missing a comma
>   How to get rid of it?

Using

```
NSString *s = @"\x12""4Vx\xc3\xaa";
NSArray *arr = @[s];
```

Can work, but I prefer not writing more NSString *s ... to do it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784969/when-did-c-compilers-start-considering-more-than-two-hex-digits-in-string-lite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with:

```
BOOL r = [res isEqualToString:@"\x124Vx\xc3\xaa"];
```

is with the `\x124` part. It seems you can only have hex values in the range `00` - `ff`. And note the removal of the `[ ]` around the string.

If you don't want the `4` to be considered part of the `\x` hex number, you can do this:

```
BOOL r = [res isEqualToString:@"\x12""4Vx\xc3\xaa"];
```

The two double-quote characters ensure the `\x` escape sequence stops where you need it to.

To eliminate the new warning about a possible missing comma when using such a string in an `NSArray`, you will need to use the older syntax to create the array:

```
NSArray *answers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"",
                     @"#",
                     @"\x12""4Vx\xc3\xaa",
                     nil
                     ];
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code did the job, but it also comes with a warning:`Concatenated NSString literal for an NSArray expression - possibly missing a comma`, is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: ok, I found the reason, I put the string literal in an array, so it gives this warning. like `@[@"1", @"\x12""4Vx\xc3\xaa"]`

Comment: I actually didn't notice the `[ ]` around the string. Yeah, that needs to go.

Comment: do you know why putting it in array will cause the warning?

Comment: It can't be in an array. The `isEqualToString:` method expects a string, not an array. Just remove the extra square brackets and it will be fine.

Comment: No you misunderstand. Actually I am writing unit tests for comparing, so I put the strings into an array, and fetch them to compare. If I put the string literal in the array, it will give the warning.

Comment: Hi Rmaddy, I tried add `nil`, but it directly report error:`Collection element of type 'void *' is not an Objective-C object`

Comment: The code I put in the answer compiles clean for me. You must have a typo.

Comment: Turned out I am using array literal, not API calls.. Thanks.